# Can an exception during OnRelease cause a component to not be disposed correctly?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, autofac

I've got the following code wiring a NHibernate ISession in Autofac for a ASP.NET application :

```
builder.RegisterAdapter<ISessionFactory, ISession>(factory => factory.OpenSession())
    .InstancePerHttpRequest()
    .OnActivated(activatedArgs =>
                 {
                     var session = activatedArgs.Instance;
                     session.BeginTransaction();
                 })
    .OnRelease(session =>
               {
                   if (session.Transaction != null && session.Transaction.IsActive)
                   {
                       try
                       {
                           session.Transaction.Commit();
                       }
                       catch(Exception e)
                       {
                           session.Transaction.Rollback();
                           throw;
                       }
                   }
               });
```

Will the session be properly disposed even with a thrown exception in the commit? Is this a correct usage of ISession together with autofac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No- throwing in `Dispose()` isn't a good idea with Autofac. The correct disposal of other component instances isn't guaranteed.

In general it should be avoided - WCF for example has a well known and long-standing usability problem because connections throw during disposal. The basic antipattern is that `Dispose()` is often called because an exception is propagating. Throwing a further exception masks the original one

*Edit:*

As a thought experiment - let's say this was supported using some try/catch magic in Autofac. What happens if `OnRelease()` throws for two different components? We can't propagate both exceptions. Further - once the exception has bubbled out of Autofac, who can catch it? All of the components servicing the request have now been released.

Hope this helps, Nick.

Comment: And OnRelease() is called when the component is Dispose()d, so this ends up being a bad ideia?  My thought here was to wrap the session usage in a transaction, whenever a session was used. Could I bother you for an alternate implementation of that behaviour?

Comment: Hi Bruno - calling Commit() in a custom action invoker (if you're using MVC) is the best option I'm aware of.

Comment: I'm using webforms, so perhaps I'll do this on a HttpModule. This only raises the issue of not creating/committing a transaction if no work's been done, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about  NHibernate ISession in Autofac but if your session class has a Dispose() method then you're not calling it anywhere. You should add a finally block after your catch block and dispose of it there.

Comment: Part of what Autofac does is disposing of components when they are released. My question has to do when I use OnRelease, and an exception is thrown there, if Autofac still disposes of it before/after passing the exception up the call chain. If it does, then calling Dispose here would be incorrect, as it would be also called further up the call chain.

Comment: @Bruno, If their implementation is correct there should be no harm in disposing it here. You can always try it and see if you get an ObjectDisposed exception :) Sorry I'm not much help since I don't know Autofac etc.